# what are these big trees?

Tags: identification

[image]
Boss just give me this pictures asked me about the variety.
Thanks a lot~

Comment: It could help if your boss told us what part of the world they come from!

Comment: Truly need to see a picture of the leaves/buds for ID.  These trees have been pruned almost pollarded a few years back. They will be unable to be IDed from a distance as their form is not natural.  This is vastly interesting, I suspect someone got lucky.  It is almost beautiful.  Please send close up of  leaves and buds nodules along the stem.  Closeup of the bark as well.  What is very much fun is that these guys are all healthy and thriving, no dead individuals.  Very interesting...

Comment: Interesting that neither google nor tineye can find a match for the image (I was hoping for more information, like a country)  Is that a tuktuk in the image? The shoulders on the road also look unlike what I've seen in Europe or North America, especially combined with the lack of a line up the middle of the road

Comment: What IS your background?  A rickshaw would indeed be a give away as is Yue Li's name.  Very good eyes for detail.  Certainly a photographer, yes?  Keeping you on FILE for future stuff...

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure its a type of pollard willow, judging by the thick bases of the trees. Not entirely sure about the bright green colour, this could just be the image or the newly developed leaves that formed, or a specific variety.

A pollard willow is a normal willow tree that is pruned back to a specific size each year, which gives this beautiful thick base and "tufts" of branches. Often used for basket and fence making, due to the springy young offshoots every year.

Salix Alba and sub-varieties are the main species used to do this in my area.

Comment: The bright green color must be the new growth coming on strong.  Have you seen this before?  Which willow do you think is managed in this way?

Comment: I have seen bright green before (although close, not quite the emerald green on display here, possibly this is due to editing of the photo?), I live in an area where this kind of willow management is very commonplace, and in the spring the new shoots are beautiful to see. I believe mainly Salix Alba and sub-varieties are used.

Comment: @stormy I'm willing to bet that photo's been enhanced colour wise - the dark purple of the mountain behind and the almost purple road surfacing strongly hint the colour's been tinkered with

Comment: @Bamboo I'm sure the contrast has been boosted -- the histogram for all channels runs from 0 to 255.  This would brighten the leaves quite a lot, completely wiping out information about the shade of green

Comment: @ChrisH - absolutely, no way are they actually that colour. Most likely willows though, they are a very light green when they first open up, but not sure which one - the leaves look quite small but impossible to say without close up. Location guess, China, Japan maybe, somewhere like that

Comment: You could probably get that bright colour straight out of camera with the low sun that comes under thick clouds as a shower clears, especially with the right camera setting but the shadows don't work for that.  There's something a little odd about the focus/blur on the road in the foreground too and some artefacts in the sky (sharpening?).  So it's probably been through a black-box filter of some sort (like an instagram high contrast or fake HDR). (@Bamboo but having written it I remember that we're on gardening.se, not photo.se)

Comment: Sigh, I've seen this fluorescent green before, just never on this scale.  Why would someone do that?  I wonder how this would have looked had they not pollarded these trees...like a covered tunnel.  Excellent observations guys, my goodness.

Comment: @ChrisH  This is not an isolated incident.  Doesn't happen very often which is amazing.  Who are you?  Could  you elect to stick around for technical questions like this?  Who cares what site it is on...it would be very cool to have our own vid expert!  Better yet our own in house go to IT dude.  Whoa thanks for stepping in!

Comment: @stormy I'm not an expert, I just know a little about photo processing. There are people who know more than me hanging around I'm sure. I check in here every so often but by no means daily. I don't tend to post a lot though.